# Python threads/processes and class vars

Tags: python, variables, parallel-processing

The question may be really stupid but I'm working on this code since this morning and now even stupid things are hard :\

I've got this code and I call it by making 8 processes and run them.
Then there's another thread that has to print infos about this 8 processes. (code is below).

```
import MSCHAPV2
import threading
import binascii
import multiprocessing

class CrackerThread(multiprocessing.Process):

    password_header = "s."
    current_pin = ""
    username = ""
    server_challenge = ""
    peer_challenge = ""
    nt_response = ""
    starting_pin = 0
    limit = 0
    testing_pin = 0
    event = None

    def __init__(self, username, server_challenge, peer_challenge, nt_response, starting_pin, limit, event):
        #threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        super(CrackerThread, self).__init__()
        self.username = username
        self.server_challenge = server_challenge
        self.peer_challenge = peer_challenge
        self.nt_response = nt_response
        self.starting_pin = starting_pin
        self.limit = limit
        self.event = event
        self.testing_pin = starting_pin        
        #self.setDaemon(True)

    def run(self):        
        mschap = MSCHAPV2.MSCHAPV2()
        pin_range = self.starting_pin+self.limit
        while self.testing_pin <= pin_range and not self.event.isSet():
            self.current_pin = "%s%08d" % (self.password_header, self.testing_pin)                      
            if(mschap.CheckPassword(self.server_challenge, self.peer_challenge, self.username, self.current_pin.encode("utf-16-le"), self.nt_response)):
                self.event.set()
                print "Found valid password!"
                print "user     =", self.username
                print "password =", self.current_pin                
            self.testing_pin+=1            
        print "Thread for range (%d, %d) ended with no success." % (self.starting_pin, pin_range)

    def getCurrentPin(self):        
        return self.testing_pin
```

---

```
def printCrackingState(threads):
    info_string = '''
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    + Starting password = s.%08d +
    +--------------------------------+    
    + Current pin       = s.%08d +
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    + Missing pins      =   %08d +
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                  '''

    while 1:        
        for t in threads:            
            printed_string = info_string % (t.starting_pin, t.getCurrentPin(), t.getMissingPinsCount())
            sys.stdout.write(printed_string)
        sys.stdout.write("--------------------------------------------------------------------")
        time.sleep(30)
```

`printCrackingState` is called by these lines in my "main":

```
infoThread = threading.Thread(target = utils.printCrackingState, args=([processes]))  
#infoThread = cursesTest.CursesPrinter(threads, processes, event)    
infoThread.setDaemon(True)
infoThread.start()
```

Now the quesion is: why `t.starting_pin` and `t.getCurrentPin()` print the SAME value?
It's like the `t.getCurrentPin()` returns the value set in the `__init__()` method and is not aware that I'm incrementing it!

Suggestions?

Comment: can you also post the code calling `printCrackingState`?

Comment: I've added the requested code.

Comment: Well, the first question is: are you sure you're actually incrementing it? Try adding a `print` inside the `while` loop in `run` and see whether you get a flood of prints to your console or not.

Comment: I did and it prints the right values!

Comment: Another point here: For every instance attribute, you've got a class attribute with the same name, that you never use. Don't do this; the only effect this can ever possibly have is to create confusion (e.g., if you make a typo in `__init__` and don't set the instance variable you thought you did, instead of an obvious `AttributeError` you get a confusing and hard-to-track-down bug).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that you're trying to update a variable in one process, and read it in another process. You can't do that. The whole point of multiprocessing, as opposed to multithreading, is that variables are not shared by default.

Read the docs, especially [Exchanging objects between processes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) and [Sharing state between processes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes), and it will explain the various ways around this. But really, there's two: either you need some kind of channel/API to let the parent process ask the child process for its current state, or you need some kind of shared memory to store the data in. And you may need a lock to protect either the channel/shared memory.

While shared memory may seem like the "obvious" answer here, you may want to time the following:

```
val = 0
for i in range(10000):
    val += 1

val = Value('i', 0)
lock = Lock()
for i in range(10000):
    with lock:
        val.value += 1
```

It's worth noting that your code would also be incorrect with threads—although it would probably work, in CPython. If you don't do any synchronization, there is no guaranteed ordering. If you write a value in one thread and read it "later" in another thread, you can still read the older value. How much later? Well, if thread 0 runs on core 0, and thread 1 on core 1, and they both have the variable in their cache, and nobody tells the CPUs to flush the cache, thread 1 will go on reading the old value forever. In practice, CPython's Global Interpreter Lock eventually synchronizes everything implicitly (so we're talking milliseconds rather than infinity), and all variables have explicit memory locations rather than being, say, optimized into registers, and so on, so you can usually get away with writing unprotected races. But, thanks to Murphy's Law, you should read "usually" as "every time until the first demo to the investors" or "until we attach the live nuclear reactor".

Comment: Got it. It worked using `Value` class to make a shared memory. I don't need locks and stuff like that because those are just some "random" infos to tell the user that the process is going and how much is left to the end, synchronization is not required.

Comment: @StepTNT: "synchronization is not required" means "it's OK if the reader never sees the updated data". Which is clearly not true, because the whole problem you came here with is that the reader never sees the updated data…

Comment: Isn't synchronization needed just to keep data consistence? (Like the ACID properties of databases). I managed to make it work with shared memory and no lock, that's why I said that synchronization was not needed (I'm coming from Java and synchronization is intended for atomic operations, that's why I said so!)

Comment: @StepTNT: First, how do you know you made it work, as opposed to making it work almost all the time in one particular CPython version on one particular platform? In the case of `multiprocessing`, as opposed to `threading`, Python effectively offers the same guarantees as the underlying OS shared memory API, which generally means you can get away with a lot more—but also means it's even harder to know exactly when you can and can't get away with it.

Comment: @StepTNT: Also, I don't know how you learned your Java, but Java has the exact same problem as Python, and in fact the memory model _requires_ it to have that problem, and the intermittent errors will usually be more frequent. If you never synchronize two threads, there is no guarantee when, or even that, a change to a (non-`volatile`) variable from one thread will show up in the other. (And if you already understand the need for `volatile` in Java, with the 5.0+ semantics, a shorter answer is: Python doesn't have `volatile`.)

Comment: As I already said, the "I don't need the synchronization" means that I'm not interested in having the exact value shown, that's why concurrence is not a problem. I need to show something in a range between 0 and 100000000 so it's not important to show 94000000 ore 94000001 in a particular moment.

Comment: @StepTNT: And as I already explained, it's perfectly legal for it to show 0 forever, and you definitely are not OK with that. (And this is just as true with Java threading as it is with Python.) You're relying on the fact that it's _unlikely_ to show 0 forever—or, worse, that it just happens not to in one test on one system. If you know how the underlying OS primitives work, and how `multiprocessing` works, you might be able to prove that the results will always be acceptable, but otherwise, you're just asking for trouble.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't get it. In my situation I have n processes writing to n different variables and one which just reads them all. So it may happen that the reader reads them before they're updated and it'll print the old value, but everything is written into a shared memory so the next reading will get a useful value instead of a 0. I've used the shared memory example that you linked in "Sharing states between processes"

Comment: I'm not sure I can explain this any better in a 600-character comment, but… one last try. Your CPU almost never actually reads from memory, shared or otherwise; it reads from a cache. How does it know when the cached value is out of date? It doesn't, unless you tell it. That's what `volatile`, `atomic`, `barrier`, `interlock`, etc. do. Otherwise, you're just counting on getting lucky enough that the cache overspills and loses your value and has to re-fetch it, or the process gets migrated to a different core.

Comment: But… if you followed the sample code, I'm pretty sure that you're using `lock=True`, which means "create a new `multiprocessing.Lock` for each `Value` instance and lock it around each access. In which case you're safe (you may be _oversynchronizing_, but you're not racing). Just don't change it to `lock=False` and you'll be fine.